# How can I print a day of the week in a locale-friendly way using NSDateFormatter?

Tags: swift, locale, nsdateformatter

I noticed `NSDateFormatter` allows for an enum called `.FullStyle` that will print `Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD`.

But how do I just print `Tuesday` in a locale-safe way?

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` has a `dateStyle` property that can be set to `.FullStyle`. `NSDateComponents` doesn't have a `dateStyle` property or anything that can be set to `.FullStyle`. I've edited your question. If you didn't mean to say `NSDateFormatter`, please edit your question to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use NSDateFormatter `dateFormat  = "cccc"`. If you need a reference for date format patterns you can take a look at this [link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Formatter {
        static let dayOfWeek: NSDateFormatter = {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "cccc"   // Stand Alone local day of week
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var dayOfWeek: String {
        return Formatter.dayOfWeek.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

print(NSDate().dayOfWeek)   // Wednesday
```

---

**Xcode 8 beta 3 • Swift 3**

```
extension DateFormatter {
    convenience init(dateFormat: String) {
        self.init()
        self.dateFormat = dateFormat
    }
}

extension Date {
    struct Formatter {
        static let dayOfWeek = DateFormatter(dateFormat: "cccc")  // Stand Alone local day of week
    }
    var dayOfWeek: String {
        return Formatter.dayOfWeek.string(from: self)
    }
}

print(Date().dayOfWeek)   // Wednesday
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"` as Leo Dabus suggests.

If you have the day of week, you can use it as an index into the formatter's `weekdaySymbols`. Example:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
let weekday = formatter.calendar.component(.Weekday, fromDate: NSDate())
let weekdaySymbol = formatter.weekdaySymbols[weekday]
// result: "Saturday" (for example)
```